# Problem with explorer.exe and dwm.exe in Windows 7

Tags: performance, graphics, windows-7, windows-explorer, dwm

I'm using Window 7 Ultimate. I get a problem with two processes, namely `explorer.exe` and sometimes `dwm.exe`.

The two processes tend to use cpu between 20-30%.

And it only occurs when **i play some game** on my PC. My PC works perfect until I play some game.

And another **important observation**:
They consume no cpu as such but only consumes **when I try to refresh** my desktop. I mean when I right-click on desktop. It takes seconds for refresh.

I have **no virus** problems.

I had already tried following things:

1. Kill explorer.exe and relaunch from task manager. (Problem still persists)
2. Kill dwm.exe, well it relaunches again. (Problem still persists)
3. Log Off and Log On. (Problem still persists)
4. Restart. Problem Solved. (But need an alternative).

Can anyone kindly suggest some quick fixes to the problem?

Comment: This should be moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those who get the same problem may refer to this question at super user asked by me.

https://superuser.com/questions/254343/window-7-problem-explorer-exe-dwm-exe

My problem solved with ShellExView.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is to be expected. Both of those are critical components of the Windows operating system.

Explorer.exe is responsible for the desktop, the file manager, the taskbar, and most visible components of the Windows shell. Generally, when you're not interacting with a particular application program, you're interacting directly with Windows Explorer. And it's still there in the background when applications *are* running, managing those applications and the underlying system.

DWM stands for ["Desktop Window Manager"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager), which should help to give away what it does. It's a graphical subsystem that was introduced in Windows Vista, and it's responsible for the fancy 3D effects that you get on your desktop now. It drives the ["Aero" user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero), so things like glass transparency, Aero Peek, Aero Shake, and a host of other eye candy features are implemented by this process.

Understanding what both of those processes are and what they do should help to explain the phenomenon you cite in your question:

> They consume no cpu as such but only consumes when i try to refresh my desktop. I mean when i right click on desktop.

When you refresh your desktop, you're invoking functionality provided by both of those processes. Explorer is responsible for drawing the desktop itself (programmatically, it's implemented as an iconic ListView control managed by Explorer), and DWM is responsible for the graphics subsystem that gets the desktop, in all its beautifully composited glory, onto the screen in the first place.

Using between 20-30% of your CPU is hardly an outrageous draw. That leaves plenty left over for your foreground applications. It's also difficult to monitor exactly what percentage of the CPU those processes are using without altering the results.

But, from the symptoms that you've described, you can be sure that you don't have a virus or anything else wrong with your computer. That's just Windows running, doing its thing. If your computer is struggling to keep up with the game that you're playing, you may need to consider upgrading some of your computer's components (namely your RAM, processor, and/or graphics card).

If you're recently upgraded your computer to Windows 7 from an earlier version (like Windows XP), and have noticed your performance slow down as a result, your graphics card may be struggling under the 800-pound gorilla that is DWM. All of the Aero effects are expensive to run—not a problem for today's overpowered and overpriced video cards that generally sit around doing nothing, but a significant performance hit for older systems that used to run just fine with older versions of the OS. You might try reverting to the Windows Classic theme, which will disable most of the Aero-themed goodness, but will also put some of the "pep" back into your computer's step. Do that by right-clicking on your desktop, selecting "Personalize", and changing your theme to Windows Classic.

Comment: Gray: I think u guys r not understanding my language. I try it other way. My PC works fast until i play any game(any of the many).But after this my PC becomes slow. Specially the refresh. When i run resource monitor i found explorer to take avg cpu 30, but i get pikes of 100 cpu usage too.

Comment: @Nitinzz: Read the last two paragraphs of my answer again. If your computer slows down when you're playing a game, then that game is the problem. There's no blaming it on `explorer.exe` or `dwm.exe`. As the rest of my answer explains, they're core processes that drive the underlying Windows operating system. You're not going to escape them by restarting your computer, and you shouldn't feel the need to try to do so, either. Edit: Yes, Explorer is going to consume nearly 100% of your CPU when you **ask it to do something**, like refresh your desktop. That's how programs work; they tax the CPU.

Comment: gray: Yes i'm already using classic theme. And any specific game may not be the problem since its the problem with every game i play. And things were fine earlier. I'm using 2gb ram, dual core intel processor, although my graphic card not quite great but its enough for the games i play. I don't play high graphic games.

Answer (score 1):

Both explorer and dwm are "necessary" files that Windows runs. Explorer.exe is basically all the user interface you see on Windows: the desktop, the taskbar, explorer, etc. Similarly, dwm.exe is the Desktop Window Manager: it governs all the effects that were added with Vista and 7, like the taskbar thumbnails that appear when you hover over a taskbar item, transparency, etc. So it makes sense that you see action on them when trying to refresh the desktop.

I've never actually looked to see how much processing power they use at any given time, so I can't say whether that's excessive or not, but there's really nothing wrong with either one; they probably ought to be running, and unless they're causing undue CPU use, you probably don't need to worry about them. And if you do need to worry about them, then it might be a consequence of your computer not being powerful enough to run Windows 7.

All that said, this isn't really a question for this site. I'm still pretty new here myself, but I think this should be moved to Superuser?

Comment: @erekalper: i'm not talking abt memory, i m talking about cpu usage. Further its a genuine problem because it takes you some seconds just in refresh, then definitely something is wrong. And Stackoverflow has the window 7 tagg, so i think its the right place to be

Comment: @Nitinzz: I'm sorry, I used the broadest sense of the word "memory" there; I've corrected it to "processing power." I wasn't discounting that this isn't a genuine problem for you, but was rather trying to discover why, as you claim you have no virus or contamination issues (an unknown, intrusive process accessing other processes would have been my first thought). So my second thought, as I said, was that maybe 7 is too much for your computer to handle. Did you recently upgrade and this is happening, or have you been running it for some time and this is a new problem?

Comment: @Nitinzz: And I said it might be more useful for Superuser because that's the site about computer issues and questions in general, while Stackoverflow is centered on programming problems... and this isn't a programming problem.

Comment: @erekalper: Slightly off-topic: There's no sense of the word "memory", no matter how broad, that could ever connote "processing power". They're very different concepts. Just thought I'd point that out in case English is not your first language. I certainly understood what you meant, but technically, they are quite distinct concepts.

Comment: @erekalper: thanx for the suggestion of superuser, but again my pc is good enough to handle win 7, and it works perfect until i play any game. Problems start after that.

Comment: @Nitinzz: It boggles the mind why you suspect `explorer.exe` and `dwm.exe` then, instead of **the game** that you just got finished playing. If I run an app, and afterwards, my computer seems broken, I'm going to blame that app. Especially if the *only* time I see problems is after running it. This answer and mine are trying to explain why the two processes you've fingered as *potential* culprits are decidedly *not* the culprits.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You're absolutely right, I realize that. I was using (abusing?) memory to mean any part of the computer that was being taxed, but you're correct, they're really quite distinct, which is why I corrected my shoddy terminology. I can't get away with sloppy responses on a site like this...

Comment: @both: but how can the small chess games, low graphic games like commandos etc all can be blamed altogether.

Comment: i'm sorry for any non sense question i ask, as i'm not so gud at o.s. concepts, specially win 7.

Comment: @Nitinzz: As we've said, and I'll try to make this as clear as possible: Windows 7 Ultimate is not an easy operating system for computers to run. It is very graphically intensive, and requires a good CPU and a good amount of RAM. It is entirely possible that running simple games on it can cause hangups or delays. This isn't a satisfying answer, I know. So to reiterate one last time, this is why I suggest you post this to Superuser: it is a sister-site of Stackoverflow, and is meant for **exactly this kind of question.** Stackoverflow is meant for programming. You'll get a better answer there.